# How to resolve findbug issue: Null passed for nonnull parameter

Tags: java, null, findbugs

I'm getting the following findbugs error:

**"Method call passes null for nonnull parameter : Null passed for nonnull parameter of getApiStatus(ApiResponse)"**

If the apiResponse is null in the CallApi method (not shown here for brevity's sake), it simply throws an exception that is caught in handleApiException and thrown again if we can't do anything else about the exception.

There is no way that a null value for apiResponse could be passed into getApiStatus() method at the botton of this code snippit.  How can I tell findbugs that this is the case without doing yet another null check on top of the null check that is done in the apiService.CallApi method? I've tried using the NonNull annotation, but that didn't resolve the issue.  Here's the code in question:

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = null;
try {
    apiResponse = apiService.CallApi(apiURL, requestObject);
}
catch (ApiException ex) {
    handleApiException(ex);
}

boolean apiStatus = getApiStatus(apiResponse);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: There is a possibility that called method handles the null exception. Spotbug could be wrong in this case. Isn't an issue with spotbug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to NOT handle the exception, but to set this method as throws ApiException. And then handle it higher up the chain. If your code gets an exeption in that try block, then handles the exception in the catch, then apiResponse can easily be null. And will then go on to try the getApiStatus method, hence passing in a null.

```
public void yourMethod() throws ApiException {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = apiService.CallApi(apiURL, requestObject);
    boolean apiStatus = getApiStatus(apiResponse);
    // Whatever else you need to do here.
}
```

Your only other option is to put the apiStatus call below the apiResponse one inside the try block, like so:

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = null;
try {
    apiResponse = apiService.CallApi(apiURL, requestObject);
    boolean apiStatus = getApiStatus(apiResponse);
} catch (ApiException ex) {
    handleApiException(ex);
}
```

Or, as you say, do a null check before calling getApiStatus, but that's not as preferable as the options above.

Comment: I ended up going with your second option because I wanted to handle the ApiException at the current layer instead of passing it on to the business class.  Thanks for the detailed analysis and giving multiple options.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the `getApiStatus(apiResponse)` will be called regardless of the `ApiException` occurring or not.

You should have this instead:

```
try {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = apiService.CallApi(apiURL, requestObject);
    // line bellow will not execute if CallApi throws ApiException
    boolean apiStatus = getApiStatus(apiResponse);
}
catch (ApiException ex) {
    handleApiException(ex);
}
// lines bellow will execute after try-catch block above
// regardless of the ApiException occurring or not
```

Answer (score 1):

If `CallApi` throws an exception, then it will be handled and control will continue to `getApiStatus`, without `apiResponse` ever being assigned anything other than the initial `null`.